# Steady state speed and steady state error.

Tags: control-theory

I got this first order block diagram below.
[image: Block diagram for closed loop speed control]

Below is the transfer function for the motor model.

[image: transfer function for model]

I tried to get an equation for the steady state speed and steady state error, but my answer doesn't seem to come out right. This looks to me like a positive feedback with the two negative signs. I tried to start with $-E(s)=-R(s)-w(s)$ but as I go further down the line, I get really confused. I know the steady state error for a negative feedback is $1\over 1+KpG(s)$ where $G(s)$ stands for the transfer function of the motor so I assumed for this question, it's the same except with the denominator as $(1-KpG(s))$ but I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Note that your block diagram has the same structure as the standard negative unit feedback block diagram with the only difference that the reference also has a negative sign. So how could you factor this out, such that you do get the structure of a standard negative unit feedback block diagram?